# Map strings to a color selected from a predefined array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, colors

I'm adding tags to my website for blog posts and I want those tags to have different background colors (picked from a predefined array of theme colors).

I want them to have the **same** background color if they're the same string value. For example a tag with the string "educational" would have the same background color as another tag that had "educational", but could be a different color than say a tag with the string value of "technology".

Given the following theme:

`const COLORS = ['pink', 'purple', 'indigo', 'blue', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'black', 'whitesmoke']`

How could I write a function that hashes the string (NOT just going by string length and Math.random) and picks randomly from that `COLORS` array by simply calling something like `stringToColor(tagName)`?

I'm aware that the tags may sometimes have the same color but as random as possible would be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hash those tags by method which converts every character of this string to ASCII code by using `charCodeAt` and then sum all of these numbers.

```js
const hashString = (string) => string
  .split('')
  .map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0))
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
```

Then you can access elements from array using this number as index. It will get you exact same element every time when you pass the same hash of word.

```js
const stringToColor = (string) => COLORS[hashString(string) % COLORS.length];
```

This modulo operator "convert" any hash number to index from 0 to COLORS array length.